# how to export data to existing excel (with header and predefined dropdown column) file using SSIS

Tags: t-sql, ssis, export-to-excel

My first post. I need to export data from sql database to an existing excel file.  The excel file has a predefined header and a couple of columns with drop downlist.  I know how to export data to a new excel using ssis but I appreciate some direction please.

[image]

Comment: I equally dislike ssis and excel so here's what I would do!  Open blank excel sheet > Click Data Tab > New Query Button > From Database > From SQL Server.  Setup the connection string and permissions for the user and the instance.  Copy in the query or view name and let them refresh at will.  Comes with filters column names and all =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either using SSIS but, you can only write into a new sheet. 
or 
open excel, go to data tab click on from other source (from drop down) pick "from SQL server'. Provide the details to get the result.

OR 
If you have management studio, you can execute the query and copy the result.

Comment: I need to do this as a sql job to automate this process

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which does not include SSIS - if that is of any use.

First I created an xlsx file with formatted headers, frozen top row and filters.
Then I saved on the server and ran the following from SQL Server 2012-

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0;Database=T:\Test\Report_Base.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [WorksheetName$]') select * from MySQLtable
```

This added the data to the excel worksheet called 'WorksheetName'.
I had an additional issue where SQL said it added x rows of data, but I could not see them.
Turns out it had added the data - just much further down than I expected.
To fix this I opened the excel, selected row 2 on and then deleted them.
Saving this version and exporting to it worked fine.